# setting a limit on a variable in a function and return error else wise in haskell

Tags: haskell

Hi i'm new to haskell and i'm trying to implement the following and I can't quite get it right

here is a basic algorithm of what i'm trying to do lets say you have

```
--define some basic example function
fun x y = x + y
--pseudo code for what i am trying to do
  x >= -1.0 || x <= 1.0  --variables x must be within this range else ERROR
  y >=  1.0 || y <= 2.0   --variables y must be within this range else ERROR
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple way to do this is as follows. This uses a [guard](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures#if_and_guards_revisited):

```
fun x y
   | x < -1.0 || x > 1.0 || y < 1.0 || y > 2.0 = error "Value out of range"
   | otherwise = x + y
```

[See here](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors) for a series of increasingly complex and sophisticated ways to report and handle errors.

Sometimes a `Maybe` type is preferable, as ivanm points out. Here's an example for completeness:

```
fun' :: Float -> Float -> Maybe Float
fun' x y
   | x < -1.0 || x > 1.0 || y < 1.0 || y > 2.0 = Nothing
   | otherwise = Just (x + y)
```

Comment: In general it's preferable to use something like `Maybe` rather than `error` though.

Comment: @ivanm: Depends on whether it's "easy" for the caller to anticipate. E.g., if a function's argument should always be positive, it seems reasonable to throw an exception if it isn't, rather than expect the caller to deal with `Maybe` every time the function is used. For something like a parser, where a parse failure might reasonably occur anywhere, sure - `Maybe` or similar is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @ivanm, you're right -- I was keeping it simple, but I added an example for completeness.